# Reduction formula Integration

Tags: integration, reduction-formula

Is it true that $I_{p,q}=\left ( \frac{p-1}{p+q} \right )I_{p-q,q}$ given that $I_{p,q}=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^{p}x \cos^q x dx$ (where $p$ and $q$ are positive integers)? If so, how?
Also, how can I evaluate $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^{p}x \cos^q x dx$ ($p$ and $q$ are positive integers) using the very expressions from the above question?

Answer (score 0):

You need not use a reduction formula. Here's why. Consider the function defined by 
$$\Gamma(s)=\int_0^\infty t^{s-1}e^{-t}dt\qquad s>0.$$
Integration by parts shows that 
$$\Gamma(s+1)=s\Gamma(s),$$
and it is easily shown that $\Gamma(1)=1$. Thus for $s=1,2,3,...$, 
$$\Gamma(s)=(s-1)!.$$
This function is known as the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). Anyway, we set $t=x^2$ and see that
$$\Gamma(s)=2\int_0^\infty x^{2s-1}e^{-x^2}dx.$$
So we see 
$$\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)=4\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty y^{2a-1}x^{2b-1}e^{-(x^2+y^2)}dydx.$$
Then we [convert to polar coordinates](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/DIPolarCoords.aspx) and get
$$\begin{align}
\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)&=4\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^\infty \sin(\theta)^{2a-1}\cos(\theta)^{2b-1}e^{-r^2}r^{2(a+b)-1}drd\theta\\
&=2\int_0^\infty e^{-r^2}r^{2(a+b)-1}2\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(\theta)^{2a-1}\cos(\theta)^{2b-1}d\theta dr\\
&=\left(2\int_0^\infty e^{-r^2}r^{2(a+b)-1}dr\right)\left(2\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(\theta)^{2a-1}\cos(\theta)^{2b-1}d\theta\right)\\
&=2\Gamma(a+b)\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(\theta)^{2a-1}\cos(\theta)^{2b-1}d\theta.
\end{align}$$
So what we have ended up showing is that
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(t)^{a}\cos(t)^{b}dt=\frac{\Gamma(\tfrac{a+1}2)\Gamma(\tfrac{b+1}2)}{2\Gamma(\tfrac{a+b}2+1)}.$$

Comment: But our syllabus says reduction formula.